# Selenium webdriver with Python crashes after upgrading to Firefox 18

Tags: firefox, selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Here is the message I recieve when trying to run: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Python27\intertwyneloginandemail", line 3, in <module>
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
 self.binary, timeout),
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
 self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 44, in launch_browser
 self._wait_until_connectable()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 86, in _wait_until_connectable
 self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))

 WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:   
 c:\\users\\aarons\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmphqwoq5 Firefox output: *** LOG addons.xpi: startup\r\n*** WARN addons.xpi: Ignoring missing add-on in C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common  
 Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore\r\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local\r\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share\r\n***
 LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\r\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\r\n"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to update selenium package to the latest version (2.29.0)

Comment: +1 - my old workaround for this was to have a directory with Firefox 15 and use that as the FirefoxBinary. Updating is much better than doing that :)

Comment: Thanks guys I was able to update it with the command: install -U selenium.

Comment: This worked for me too.....Updated selenium with the same command...Thanks guys...